Why not place an exhaust fan behind the toilet instead of just on the ceiling?
The toilet is typically the primary source of odors in a bathroom. So why do we only install ventilation fans on the ceiling? Wouldn't it make more sense to place a fan directly behind the toilet to immediately capture and remove odors before they spread throughout the room? This way you'd have two fans: a standard one on the ceiling and an extra fan on the wall behind the toilet.
It would look approximately like this (illustration generated by Gemini):


Note: this is a practical question. I'm planning a bathroom remodel and want to understand whether my idea makes sense.

The main use of a bathroom fan is to remove wet warm humid air(from showers).  Your stinks are a low secondary use to remove.

@crip659 sure but if you have a strong sense of smell the stinks can be very important too. I can smell lingering smells for up to 20-30 minutes, even with the exhaust fan turned on and otherwise doing a good job removing humidity.

One fan is required by code, but code usually deals with the minimum requirements.  I doubt if there is anything preventing you from having more fans except your wallet.  Might want it on a timer, but they are quite common in bathrooms.  Turn it on and it turns off in five/ten minutes.

Fans work great for removing humidity after a shower because the moisture is mostly contained in the upper layers of warm air. Also you don't really notice the small amount of moisture that does escape.


So why do we only install ventilation fans on the ceiling?

Cost.   Many folks wouldn't put even one in if they weren't required.
The main purpose of a fan is to remove humidity from a bathroom.   Unless the humidity can be removed, condensation from a hot shower/bath can damage the room.   So code states that there must be a way to remove that humidity.
A fan needs both an exhaust and power.   That's often easiest to accomplish in the ceiling.   If you combine it with a light in the same unit, it saves time during construction as well.
Behind a toilet might be on an interior wall where ducting would be impractical or expensive.
Odors don't damage the house, so there's no reason for code to specify a fan for that purpose.   If you want it and you have the money, no problems putting one in.   But a home builder isn't going to get back the investment it would take to add one.

2 reasons adding another fan won't work to eliminate smells:
Smells are fast
They can outrun almost any fan - even with the fan on, by the time you are finished your business, the smell has completely filled the room. As fresh air is brought in by the fan it quickly gets diffused with the smell. The smell is only diluted slightly over time as a result.
Smells only take a few molecules
It only takes a very small concentration of molecules to be detected as a smell. The fan does remove some molecules with the exhaust air and brings in fresh air but the fan is basically just slowly diluting the smell and it keeps spreading. If you leave the door open after you are done the smell will migrate to the rest of the house even with the fan on.
So what to do?
If you left a bad stink, spray some deodorizer to cover it with a stronger smell, leave the fan on and close (or mostly close) the door when you leave.

Thanks, I think I should run an experiment first before committing to this project

Exhaust fans are there mainly (the reason of the code) to take moisture out of the room so that mold and other pollutants don't start growing.    There is no code regulations for poop smells.
Adding a second exhaust right behind the toilet is also fine.    But you would still be required to have a ceiling exhaust.

Two reasons come to mind as to why a fan in close proximity to the toilet could be unpleasant for the toilet occupant. First, noise: a fan just two or three feet away from one's ears will be perceived more loudly than one in the ceiling. Second, air movement: a fan this close to the partially-disrobed toilet user will cause an air current which may cause the person to feel a chill.
Also, one reason why having a fan low and another high could be detrimental: convective air currents, or the "stack effect". Seasonally, at least, warm air will exit the high fan while cooler air is drawn in through the lower fan. This will increase HVAC costs as conditioned air is lost to the outdoors. It may also cause the toilet seat to be extra chilly when one takes a seat during cold weather.
These things can be mitigated of course, but they're risks to consider.

Imagine a large exhaust fan might fix all conditions.  Most bathroom fans are just big enough for the space.  A bigger sucker should remove smells also.

You would need some very large industrial fan - like in a wind tunnel - to eliminate any smells

@crip659 in theory a 50 CFM fan can recycle 100% of the air in 5-6 minutes in a typical bathroom. But air mixing is not perfect so in practice it takes 20-30 minutes.

@JonathanReez yes but the speed of the diffusion is quicker than any normal fan can overcome

@DJ AFAIK diffusion is extremely slow. Smells travel relatively fast due to being given initial momentum by the colon, convection caused by the temperature difference between the smell and the surrounding air and due to air currents caused by human movement. And of course if the exhaust fan is on, it speeds up the mixing even more.
